# Can't include extended WPF-Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces, toolkit

I would like to use the extended wpf toolkik(https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) but I am too stupid to include it.

I followed these steps:

1. Reference the binaries in your project:
     Reference WPFToolkit.Extended.dll in your project (Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.dll for the 
     datagrid control)
2. Add a using statement ("using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;" for most of the controls, "using
   Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid;" for the datagrid control) to the top of .cs files
3. Add a new xmlns (xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" for most of the controls,
   xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid" for the datagrid control) to the top of XAML 
   files

The using-statement in the cs-file is working! But in my xaml-file I can´t find the toolkit!

I added this: `xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"`
but this namespace does not exist.

[image]

so what are I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add Wpf toolkit via Nuget within VS, I had the same issue but installing via Nuget was easier and it actually worked...

Answer (score 5):

As @rshepp points out in the comments, it's much easier to install the WPF Toolkit by Nuget package.

Go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.

Type `Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit` in the console window.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the codeplex version any more. There are newer versions available at GitHub and they can be easyly installed from VS.

[Fork of WpfExToolkit (except Xceed Avalon Dock) on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfExtendedToolkit)

Name at nuget: `DotNetProjects.Extended.Wpf.Toolkit`

[Fork of AvalonDock (formerly in Xceed WpfExToolkit) on GitHub](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock)

As of September 2020 the free version of the original Xceed Toolikit does not contain the DataGrid and the AvalonDock any more. The version 3.8 ist still downloadble and usuable in any projects. The version 4.0 must not be used in commercial projects.

[Orignal Xceed Toolkit (3.8 and the newer versions)](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit)

Xceed announces that the version 3.8 will be only available until December 31st, 2020

> To clarify the situation and give everyone the advance notice that should have been given before changing our licensing model, we have decided to re-publish the last version of the Extended Toolkit (v3.8) as per the initial MS-PL license with the original terms, until December 31st, 2020. This will be the last version to be released under such license, and the next release will be under our new community license, which only allows non-commercial use.